# Function of sum of squares only has a minimum

Tags: functions, optimization

I have heard that if we have a function $f$ of two variables that is the sum of squared expressions, then $f$ cannot have a maximum, so the only extremum it can have is a minimum.

I don't even know where to start with a proof.

Comment: Sum of squared polynomials?

Answer (score 2):

> if we have a function $f$ of two variables that is the sum of squared expressions, then f cannot have a maximum

That does not hold true as written. For example:

- $\displaystyle f(x,y)=\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+2}\right)^2\,$ has a global maximum at $x=y=0\,$, and no minimum;
- $f(x,y)=\big(\sin(x)\big)^2+\big(\cos(y)\big)^2\,$ has infinitely many local maxima and minima.

The statement could become true, however, if additional conditions were added, for example that $\,f\,$ is a *polynomial* function.

Comment: Or even more simply, the function $f$ with value $f(x,y)=0$ for every $(x,y)$.

Comment: It also has both a maximum and minimum, thus contradicting both points of the initial statement.